Is there a (standard) way to combine the Bayes Factor?
I'm currently working on an extremely large dataset that consists a large number of individual (and independent) objects. What I am doing is fitting two completely different models to each object in the data set and a part of my output is the Bayesian evidence.
For further clarification, I fit my first model to all 100 objects and I get 100 Bayesian evidences for each object. Then I fit a different model to the same 100 objects and again, get a bayesian evidence for all. I can compute the bayes factor through the ratio of the evidences to compare a single object. However, I am trying to understand, overall, which model performs better over the entire dataset. Is there a 'standard' way to approach a task such as this, where you combine the Bayes factor to get the overall best performance of a model?
Based on some (light) reading, this link says that you can multiply the Bayes factor to get a combined study model performance result https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.2217331120#:~:text=Thus%2C%20the%20Bayes%20factor%20for,factors%20from%20the%20individual%20studies.
However, aside from this, I haven't seen to find much else to corroborate this method.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated
Thank you

No, not in general.
Assuming that within each model the observations are independent, you can multiply the likelihood ratios for point values but you usually cannot multiply the Bayes factors if the models are not point estimates.  Let's suppose you are tossing a coin four times with unknown probability $p$ of Heads, and you have four models with different priors for $p$:

$M_1: p = \frac12$
$M_2: p = \frac23$
$M_3: p$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ so with density $1$ $\big($with expectation $\frac12\big)$
$M_4: p$ distributed on $[0,1]$ with density $2p$ $\big($with expectation $\frac23\big)$

and you observe $T,T,H,T$.
Comparing $M_1$ and $M_2$,

the likelihood ratios and Bayes factors for the individual observations are $\frac{1-\frac12}{1-\frac23}=\frac 32$, $\frac 32$ again, $\frac{\frac12}{\frac23}=\frac 34$, and $\frac 32$ again,
while the overall likelihood ratio and Bayes factor is $\frac{81}{32}\approx 2.53$, which is their product.

But comparing $M_3$ and $M_4$,

the Bayes factors for the individual observations are $\frac{\int_0^1 (1-p)\, dp}{\int_0^1 2p(1-p)\, dp}=\frac{\frac12}{\frac13}=\frac 32$, $\frac 32$ again, $\frac{\int_0^1 p\, dp}{\int_0^1 2p^2\, dp}=\frac{\frac12}{\frac23} =\frac 34$, and $\frac 32$ again,
while the overall  Bayes factor is $\frac{\int_0^1 (1-p)^2p(1-p)\, dp}{\int_0^1 2p(1-p)^2p(1-p)\, dp}=\frac{\frac1{20}}{\frac1{30}} =\frac32=1.5$, which is not their product.


Thank you for taking the time to answer and for explaining the reasoning - I was initially skeptical of the article as there wasn't much to back it up and I couldn't find the same information elsewhere but wasn't sure of the math behind it, so that helped make things clearer

Yes, you could do this, although your evidence measure will be in the form of posterior model probabilities. This approach essentially boils down to using the posterior model probabilities of object $i$ as prior model probabilities for object $i + 1$ (see this paper). However, since you are not updating the parameter estimates, the resulting measure of evidence does not yield a coherent Bayes factor (see here), which means that the product of Bayes factors over all objects is in general not equal to the Bayes factor calculated over the entire data set. This is also excellently discussed by Henry in the answer above.
In your case, I'm wondering whether you would not want to fit a hierarchical model, and evaluate the fit of your model over the entire dataset directly.

Thanks for linking the papers and also explaining! Could I ask (perhaps rather naively but this is a relatively new field for me), in regards to your final comment, how would you go about evaluating this over the entire dataset, as my observations require that a model is fit to each object in the dataset

I don't know enough about your data and model to give concrete advice, but from your question, I inferred that you fit the same model to each object (i.e., having the same set of parameters). In that case, you could define a single model for all objects, where the parameters are allowed to vary over the subjects. See, for instance, the book "Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models" by Gelman and Hill. Although the book is on regression, the ideas apply more widely.

I see! apologies, I was a little sparse on the details. I'm fitting for the same parameters by defining the same prior widths for any given model, but the parameters themselves are constrained from the fitting process. Only thing that is the same for each model is what actual parameters for which I define priors for. Thanks for suggesting the book and for the helpful advice - I will check it out
